# php imagick paint all non transparent pixels one color

Tags: php, imagick

I need to convert all non transparent pixels to one  color (e.g. black).

I can only use the methods exposed by the php imagick extension http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php

as `exec()` is blocked on the server.

what would be the quickest route to achieve this?

Comment: In the end I created a black pseudo image and copied the opacity from the original image to the new pseudo image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I created a black pseudo image and copied the opacity from the original image to the new pseudo image